# What can make Class::Loader fail where "use" and "new" do not?

Tags: perl, cgi, cpan

I'm working on a very large CGI application that uses [Crypt::RSA](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-RSA), which is properly installed.  I get a "attempted to call a null reference as a function" type of error (I can't go back to get the exact error right now because we had to rollback for a release date) when I try to run any the embedded library.  I trace the null reference to Crypt::RSA's constructor, which uses [Class::Loader](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-Loader) to enable Crypt::RSA::ES::OAEP.

I replaced the class loader with a "use" and a "new", and that part works fine, though the library still fails in many points.  Obviously something is wrong with my environment.  I'm just not certain as to what.  Can anyone give me any leads?

Comment: Have you tried running the tests for Crypt::RSA?

Comment: Yes, they all succeed perfectly.

Comment: Do you get this error in both development environment and server environment?

Comment: No, just staging.

At this point I have resolved the issue for myself, though not its root cause.  I'm about to post how I solved it for future reference.  I wouldn't mind if someone finds the full facts behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after 12 hours of digging into it, I got this working.

Here's what was going on (but not why).  Whenever I called `eval()` on a quoted `use` or `require` statement (as occurs in Class::Loader, but also in other locations in the Crypt:: framwork), it failed to see paths that were otherwise included as Perl classpaths.  Since most quoted use/require objects simply assume the class will be there, very few useful errors were thrown out at me.  I would dump `@INC` to file, outside an eval block, and everything would be there.

Ironically, I used the same setup in dev vs staging, and it worked in dev, but not in staging.  I must also point out that FindBin (I shouldn't be using it in CGI, I know, but Crypt uses it) was flailing up and down about /dev/null in staging, but not in development.

Since I can't easily compare versions or global configs, that's where my quest ends.

How I resolved the issue for myself in Crypt::RSA was to disable all commands tied to FindBin, and hard-code `requir`e references for anything my code would ever access.  I did a require in Crypt::RSA for Crypt::RSA::ES::OAEP and one in Crypt::Random::Generator for Crypt::Random::Provider::rand

Hope this helps anyone in the future who has the problem.  Anyone who can suggest the why of it, please respond and I'll add it to complete the post.

Comment: Is there one particular eval{} that the use/require is in?  Can you use Data::Dumper to shoot out \@INC inside and outside the eval{}?

Comment: I don't have full source access at this moment because it's here at work and I was plugging my project into a co-workers for this.  I'd build a hand-made example but I may not be able to replicate the conditions.

Particularly, though, I caught it in:
eval("require $module");
In Class::Loader.